# Joining on a coalesce

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I think I'm close to a solution but not quite there yet. I have two tables that I want to join on a given ID if it exists, but to defer to a different column as the join condition if that ID doesn't exist.

Something like:

```
T1:
session, ID, path
1001, 1, homepage
1001, NULL, about


T2:
ID, path, type
1, homepage, A
2, about, Z
```

With the desired result of:

```
session, ID, path, type
1001, 1, homepage, A
1001, 2, about, Z
```

I've tried this with:

```
select * from t1 inner join t2 
on (t1.id = t2.id) or (t1.path = t2.path)
```

But this produces some unexpected duplicates. I want to do something like

```
select * from t1 inner join t2
on coalesce(t1.id, t1.path) = t2.id
```

But this won't work right since the path won't map to the ID in the other table.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: having that example  - what is expected output?

Comment: Added expected output. Should've been more clear originally.

Comment: Please show sample data for which you get "unexpected duplicates". With the sample data you  have shown, you'd get exactly the result you are after.

Answer (score 1):

You want a default value.  Here is one method that uses two `left join`s:

```
select t2.*, coalesce(t1.path, t1d.path) as path
from t2 left join
     t1 
     on t1.id = t2.id left join
     t1 t1d
     on t1d.id is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Below example is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table1` AS (
  SELECT 1001 session, 1 id, 'homepage' path UNION ALL
  SELECT 1001, NULL, 'about'
), `project.dataset.table2` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 'homepage' path, 'A' type UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'about', 'Z' 
)
SELECT 
  session,
  IFNULL(t1.id, t2.id) id, 
  IFNULL(t1.path, t2.path) path, 
  type
FROM `project.dataset.table1` t1
JOIN `project.dataset.table2` t2
ON (t1.id = t2.id) OR (t1.path = t2.path)
```

with output

```
Row session id  path        type     
1   1001    1   homepage    A    
2   1001    2   about       Z
```

I realized you might want to join based on `path` column ONLY if one or both `id` is/are NULL. In this case your ON clause should be as below

```
ON t1.id = t2.id 
OR (
  (t1.id IS NULL OR t2.id IS NULL) 
  AND t1.path = t2.path
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best I can come up with is:

```
select
    t1.session,
    coalesce(t1.ID, t2.ID) as ID,
    t2.path,
    t2.type
from
    t1
    inner join t2 on
        (t1.ID = t2.ID) or
        (t1.ID is null and t1.path = t2.path)
```

But this might still give undesired duplicates. I cannot judge your data design, but if the result gives duplicates, the problem might be found in problematic (duplicate and/or ambiguous) data within your tables `t1` and/or `t2`.

It also immediately striked me as an issue that field `ID` clearly can be NULL in table `t1`. From my point of view, that would mean that the relation between tables `t1` and `t2` could be considered "optional". If not, it would be better to define field `ID` in table `t1` as a required value.